# Writing a shell in C

Tags: c, shell

I am attempting to write a shell in C, but am running into a problem. The shell is supposed to operate in a loop, prompting the user each time, each time reading and parsing text from stdin. The argument is then divided up into tokens, and places each token into an argument vector. The code then forks a child, and then runs a command using the argument vectors as parameters. The code then waits for the child to terminate, and prints statistics about the child (runtime, etc). The problem is, whenever we run the program, when we enter ls /home (for example), it does not list the home directory, instead it lists the directory that we are currently in. In addition, if we try to add a new variable to the code, the code stops working.  Any idea how to resolve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define BUFFERSIZE 129

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    int status;
    int who = RUSAGE_CHILDREN;
    struct rusage usage;
    struct rusage before_usage;
    struct timeval start, end;
    while(TRUE){
    printf("==>:  ");
    char input_string[BUFFERSIZE];
    memset(input_string, '\0', BUFFERSIZE);
    fgets(input_string, BUFFERSIZE-1, stdin);

        int i = 0;
        char* input_arguments[32]; //Pointers to what the commands will be
        char* token; //The specific piece of the input "ls" or "/home"
    char* program;
    int run_exec = 1; //To say whether execvp will run


    token = strtok(input_string, " ");
    char* prog = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    memset(prog, '\0', strlen(token));
    strncpy(prog, token, strlen(token));
    program = prog;
    printf("PROGRAM: %s\n", prog);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");


    if(strncmp(program, "exit", 4) ==0)
        exit(0);

        while(token != NULL && i < 32){

        printf("TOKEN: %s \n", token);
        char* tmp = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        memset(tmp, '\0', strlen(token)+1);
        strncpy(tmp, token, strlen(token));
        input_arguments[i]=tmp;
        printf("INPUT: %s \n", input_arguments[i]);

        if(strcmp(program, "cd") == 0){
            chdir(input_arguments[0]);
        run_exec = 0;
        printf("EXEC: %d\n", run_exec);
    }

    printf("%d\n", i);
    i++;
    size_t tmp2 = 50;
    printf("%s\n", getcwd(tmp, tmp2));

    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    printf("IN LOOP\n");
}
input_arguments[i] = NULL;
printf("AFTER LOOP\n");

if(fork() != 0){
    int start_time = gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    if(run_exec == 1){
        getrusage(who, &before_usage);
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            int end_time = gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
            double wall_time_passed = (end.tv_sec -start.tv_sec)*1000
                + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec)/1000;
            getrusage(who, &usage);
            double user_time = (usage.ru_utime.tv_sec*1000 +
                usage.ru_utime.tv_usec/1000);
            double system_time = (usage.ru_stime.tv_sec*1000 
                + usage.ru_stime.tv_usec/1000);

//long page_faults = 0;
//long soft_faults = 0;
//long invol = 0;
//long vol = 0;
            printf("Number of Page Faults: %ld \n", usage.ru_majflt -before_usage.ru_majflt);
        //printf("soft_faults: %lu\n", soft_faults);
        printf("Number of Page Reclaims: %ld \n",                                usage.ru_minflt - before_usage.ru_minflt);
        //printf("soft_faults: %lu\n", soft_faults);
        printf("Number of times preempted involuntarily: %ld \n",                usage.ru_nivcsw - before_usage.ru_nivcsw);
        printf("Number of times preempted Voluntarily: %ld \n",                     usage.ru_nvcsw - before_usage.ru_nivcsw);
            printf("User Time: %f \n", user_time);
            printf("System Time: %f \n", system_time);
            printf("Wall-Time: %f \n", (wall_time_passed));
    }
}

else{
    if(run_exec == 1){
    printf("RUNNING EXEC: %s, %s \n", program, *input_arguments); 
    printf("EXEC: \n", execvp(program, input_arguments));
    }

}
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Isn't better if you use `getchar()` and then let the lexer discover what is it?

Comment: I suggest studying source codes of simpler but stable shells like heirloom-sh: http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html

Comment: Do you really want to exit if the user types `exitstatus` - or some other word that starts with `exit`? [That is, if you didn't try to use an uninitialized pointer to char that is a very similar name to the one that you actually wanted to use in `strcmp`].

Answer (score 1):

Try to reformat your variables according to following example:

```
....
if(run_exec == 1){
   //printf("RUNNING EXEC: %s, %s \n", program, *input_arguments); 
   //printf("EXEC: \n", execvp(program, input_arguments));
   char* args[] = { "ls", "/home" };
   execvp(args[0], args);
}
.....
```

Your code was commented, and replaced with simple array "ls", "/home"

or, to be more specific - you have to set 
input_arguments[0] to program name, and begin add program parameters from input_arguments[0].
e.g.

```
input_arguments[0] = "ls"
input_arguments[1] = "/var/log/"
```

here is patch for your code:

```
27c27
<         int i = 0;
---
>         int i = 1;
38a39
>     input_arguments[0]=prog;
106a108
>
```

Comment: I actually found a different way to patch the program, but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Several things here:

1. Each time you hit enter in your program, it spans a child which ends up waitpid'ing. Is that desirable?
2. ```
   char* tmp = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
   memset(tmp, '\0', strlen(token)+1);
   strncpy(tmp, token, strlen(token));
   ```

   is mostly called [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html).
3. By the way, if you actually use strlen(token) and it **returns**, then token[strlen(token)] is already '\0', because that's how strlen knows how to stop, thus, the memset above is unnecessary (if you do the strncpy with that length).
4. Your main problem is that you didn't correctly understand the [execvp man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execvp.html).
   It states the following:

   > When a C-language program is executed as a result of this call, it shall be entered as a C-language function call as follows:
   >
   > int main (int argc, char *argv[]);

   Later, it goes on and says:

   > The arguments represented by arg0,... are pointers to null-terminated character strings. These strings shall constitute the argument list available to the new process image. The list is terminated by a null pointer. **The argument arg0 should point to a filename that is associated with the process being started** by one of the exec functions.

   That's clearly the point you missed. The first argument to the argv parameter must be the same (or an allowed variation of the ) value passed as the path argument.

More on that, usually shells may explore the PATH variables themselves and replace the process image via an execve call (the last e is because shells usually let you modify the environment variables), and they pass as *path the actual path where the file was found inside the PATH, and the argv[0] argument *as it was entered* by the user.

About that, the POSIX standard says that

> The requirement on a Strictly Conforming POSIX Application also states that the value passed as the first argument be a filename associated with the process being started. [...] In some cases the filename passed is not the actual filename of the file [...]

So, if you have an executable like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("I was called as %s\n", argv[0]); return 0;
}
```

You can compile it as `test`, but symlink it to `another_test`.

When run as `test`, it shall say `I was called as test`, but not when run as another_test. That makes sense because programs may need to know how were they invoked. busybox, for example needs that to happen in order to know what does the user want.

But the code you posted is not just about adding some `input_arguments[0] = program` and starting the "int i" in 1. Those stuff I put above is true also: don't reinvent the wheel, strdup is already there and you should use instead of malloc+memset+strncpy. It's three function calls less and the notion of what the code does is much more condensed.

And each time the loop ends it spawns a child, and it doesn't mind if the program didn't spawn (maybe the program did not exist). Why not fork *after* checking `run_exec`?
Why not wait for **that** specific thread you spawned (the pid_t that fork() returns on the parent)?

Why not kill the child process if it can't spawn the image?
Currently, if the child process fails in the execvp call, it will be the one who asks for more commands, and once killed, the parent will print its statistics and continue the job. That is probably unintended and for sure counter-intuitive.

Besides, I don't know if you noticed, but you don't check for EOF in stdin, which may kill you if you're being feed from a file and not interactively (or if a user inputs EOF [Ctrl.+D]). You should probably bind the exit action to EOF too, or you won't ever finish "consuming" script files.

Comment: I forgot to mention a MAJOR part of this... do you Know how to write the shell so that it can handle processes run in the background?

Comment: @user2766621 use `fork`

Comment: @user2766621 processes "in the background" (is this your homework?) are normal processes. Difference is that they're not being waitpid'ed. Or they are, but with the [WNOHANG](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wait.html) flag, just to collect zombies. (E.g., call `waitpid((pid_t)-1, *loc, WNOHANG)` inside the loop, before asking for input)